# Why was R2D2 in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-wars

Related question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13420/star-wars-referencing-star-trek-or-vice-versa)

As you can see in the picture I've taken from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13420/star-wars-referencing-star-trek-or-vice-versa/13422#13422) (below) R2D2 can be pretty clearly seen in the opening battle in *Star Trek* (2009) and *Star Trek Into Darkness* (kudos Richard).  My question: **What is the out-of-universe reason for including R2D2 in a *Star Trek* film?**

Bonus question: although I doubt there is one, **is there an *in-universe* reason provided for R2 being here?**

[image: R2 in Star Trek]

[image: R2 Into Darkness]

Comment: The question I've linked to I think is different from mine, as I'm specifically asking about **this individual case** and what the out-of-universe (and in-universe) reason(s) is/are

Comment: Daaang! Why are people downvoting this totally legit question?

Comment: @Lexible Happens to me a lot lol; I don't really care any more

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is simple: **Because JJ Abrams can.**

From [Yahoo movies](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/bp/easter-egg-artist-j-j-abrams-uses-unlikely-220401105.html):

> "R2's really been in all of the movies I've done, really for no other
>   reason than I'm a huge fan, and when I was a kid I realized that R2
>   was also in 'Close Encounters,'" Abrams told us at last night's "Star
>   Trek Into Darkness" Blu-ray release party. "Actually, I'm putting a
>   'Star Wars' character into 'Star Trek' as an homage to 'Close
>   Encounters.' So there you go."

People like R2D2 enough to put him [everywhere](http://uproxx.com/gammasquad/2013/09/r2-d2-in-other-movies-star-trek-into-darkness/):

Steven Spielberg
[image]
[image]

Michael Bay
[image]

There is no need for a convoluted answer to everything...

Comment: Please don't put in a placeholder answer until you have all the details ready. It doesn't help you.

Comment: I don't think it's really necessary to repeat the pictures I've already got in the question

Comment: @N_Soong They weren't there when I was adding stuff to my answer.

Comment: The picture from *Star Trek* was always in the original post

Comment: @N_Soong Was it? Whoops

Comment: Now we need the "Grand Unified R2 Fanfic" to tie all these appearances together in-canon.

Comment: "Because Jar Jar Abrams doesn't give a stuff about canon" is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've expanded on this in my answer to the question [Star Wars referencing Star Trek or vice-versa?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13420/star-wars-referencing-star-trek-or-vice-versa/102764#102764), but the essence is that Lucas' company Industrial Light & Magic produced the visual effects for the Star Wars and Star Trek movies, as well as many others.

Chances are some of their employees were having fun.

Answer (score 1):

Easy in-universe answer.  Star Trek is set in a fictional future of our own planet.  Star Wars already exists in our world.  It would still exist in the future.  Someone on one of the ships was a Star Wars fan, and built an R2 unit - which would probably not be hard in a Star Trek future.

Comment: Is there a source for this claim?