# What are the instances of Star Wars ships/droids being inserted into Star Trek episodes and movies?

Tags: star-trek, star-wars, spaceship, droids, crossovers

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Star_Trek_and_Star_Wars) wikipedia entry it claims the following:

> A few references to Star Wars have been inserted into Star Trek films;
>   for fleeting moments **one can see ships and droids from Star Wars**. Most
>   Star Trek films and some TV episodes used Industrial Light and Magic,
>   founded to provide effects for Star Wars, for their special effects.

Is there a listing or does anybody know of the specific Star Trek episodes and/or movies where these Star Wars ships/droids are inserted?

If you can supply not only the episode/movie names, but also the point in the episode/movie, a screenshot, or time stamp that would be helpful.

Comment: [to get you started](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97174/5184)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instances being referred to are probably in the Star Trek reboots:

[image: R2 in Star Trek]

*Star Trek* (2009)

[image: R2 Into Darkness]

*Star Trek into Darkness* (2013)

As to why, see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97174/22917)

Comment: It's ashame this question was closed because I think there were probably a lot more, but I'll go ahead and award a correct answer on this one and both of those shots are pretty cool, gotta love R2.