# Is there a pair of alien species, one in Star Wars, one in Star Trek, that are too similar for coincidence?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, aliens

We all know that there are a huge number of different alien species created for the *Star Wars* and *Star Trek* universes.

I'm wondering if there's a pair of species that are so similar, it doesn't seem like it can be a coincidence.  The creators may be influenced, intentionally or not.   Or if there's evidence of plagiarism, that would be a good part of an answer.

Before someone answers "people":  In order to satisfy the question, it means the candidates can't be human (obviously) and can't match some simple description whose conception predates *Star Trek* and *Star Wars* (examples: human with green skin; anthropomorphic lizard, etc).

Comment: http://www.sporcle.com/games/Hejman/live_long_and_have_a_bad_feeling_about_this :-)

Comment: Related, not a dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13420/star-wars-referencing-star-trek-or-vice-versa

Comment: The only thing I have learned from this exercise is that *Star Wars* has better make up.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## The Breen vs. the Ubese bounty hunters

[image: Comparative picture showing The Breen on the left and The Ubese on the right; the Breen's helmet is silver and pointed at the mouth with a single green horizontal visor slot to see out of; the Ubese is similar in shape but brown on the bottom, silver on top and the visor slot it black]

This is probably the best and most definitive example of a character's appearance being copied between the two works.  Many Internet forums report the existence of an interview in which *Deep Space Nine* costume designer Robert Blackman addressed the Breen issue explicitly, indicating that the Breen helmet was **based directly** on the Ubese helmet (specifically, Leia's in *Return of the Jedi*), and that this was intended as an homage.

If I can locate a transcript or video of the interview, I will add it here.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the question IS a [dupe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13420/star-wars-referencing-star-trek-or-vice-versa)...

Comment: @randal'thor:  Well, obviously the question is not the same.  That doesn't mean it might not have the same answer.   That's not a dupe.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Dupe-closing is for questions that _have an answer_ elsewhere as well as for those that _have been asked_ elsewhere. At least that's how I understood it.

Comment: @randal'thor:  Sure but, I would apply the test:  If I was looking for the answer to question B, would I reasonably find question A and expect question A to provide and answer to question B without reading it.  In this case, I think that's a pretty big stretch.   It doesn't mean we shouldn't link to the related question.

Comment: @randal'thor:  At any rate, by Praxis's own admission, this is a similarity in costume, not alien appearance, which is why it satisfies the other question, and possibly not this one.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the uni-eye thing predates both, as well as the gassy-mask thing. Now the 2 in combination...?

Comment: I don't understand how similar helmets = similar organisms.

Comment: @WadCheber: The question didn't specify anything about the underlying organism.  If it were inadmissible, the OP would have ruled it out by now....

Comment: @Praxis - The question asks about species.  Helmets aren't species.  They're helmets.  The OP said that this answer satisfies another question , but "possibly not this one".

Comment: You know I don't nitpick your answers, but in this case, anything could be under that helmet, from Princess Leia to Chewbacca to a Vulcan, to a human-shaped bag full of tribbles.

Comment: @WadCheber: I know you don't, no worries.  I didn't take it as a notice at all, just as a legitimate question about whether it fits the question.  I was uncertain myself, and in previous edits I had cautionary statements.  But new comments from OP below the question indicate the answer is acceptable.  I completely agree that there is a nonzero probability of a human shaped bag of tribbles! :-)

Comment: @WadCheber: Meant "didn't take it as a nitpick at all"...Android's autocorrect thought "tribble" was fair game but not "nitpick".

Comment: @WadCheber and Praxis:   I'm actually on the fence about whether this satisfies the question.  But I'm constantly annoyed by people mincing the letter of the question and not the intent.   The intent was character design.   Does that include costume?  Well, since it's so integral to both the Ubese and Breen, okay I'll take it.    I'm not 100% sure, but since this seems to be **the best answer** even if it's not clear if it satisfies the question, it gets ✓

Comment: ... but if someone comes up with a quote from Rick Berman that says Species 8472 were supposed to look like Jabba the Hut, but the computers messed up the CGI, then the ✓ moves.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : It's more like Jabba the Hutt in the remastered *A New Hope* was supposed to look like Jabba the Hutt, but they messed up the CGI.

Answer (score 14):

## The Mon Calamari from *Star Wars*...

[image: Admiral Ackbar in the white uniform with a fish-like head: brown bulbus at the top with yellow eyes on the side, big nostrils with no nose and small tentacle-like beard]

## ...and these guys from *The Next Generation*.

[image: 2 purple coloured Antedeans side by side in a room; they have similar shaped heads to the Mon Calamari with fin like mohawks and white eyes on the side of their heads]

The latter are Antedeans from the *TNG* episode "The Manhunt".

Comment: I think we should stick with the new convention that the answer to every question is "**these guys**"

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I agree.  There should also be a these-guys tag.

Comment: These aren't that similar. Besides, both are predated by the Silurians from Doctor Who.

Comment: @RogueJedi : Hmm...the sea-dwelling Silurians introduced in *Doctor Who* prior to *Star Trek / Star Wars* don't really look like these, but it's probably a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: Squid != fish. They're mollusks. ;)

Comment: I think one could argue that anthropomorphic animals of any sort are likely to predate both *ST* & *SW*. Unless it was something really unusual & specific, like an ant-lion or something.

Comment: Fun fact: one of those guys is Mick Fleetwood!

Comment: @Lexible Don't you mean "squid ∉ fish"?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard That is also true, as is fish ∉ squid.

Comment: @Lexible Fish ∩ squid = Ø

Answer (score 7):

Gorn from ST and Bossk from SW look similar.

[image: Comparative image showing Gorn on the left and Bossk on the right; Gorn is a green skinned anthropomorphic lizard with a red and gold coloured tunic and red gloves, its head it crocodile-like; Bossk is the same but more of a scale-like skin and browner: he wears a yellow spacesuit with a white vest]

Comment: (examples: human with green skin; **anthropomorphic lizard**, etc)

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the greedy, big nosed, big eared Ferengi and the greedy, big nosed and big eared flying merchant from *Star Wars I*.

I assume it's no direct plagiarism, but in both cases the character designers where influenced by the same antisemite stereotypes:

> Gerald Krefetz summarizes the myth as "[Jews] control the banks, the money supply, the economy, and businesses—of the community, of the country, of the world".[66] Krefetz gives, as illustrations, many slurs and proverbs (in several different languages) which suggest that Jews are stingy, or greedy, or miserly, or aggressive bargainers.[67] During the nineteenth century, Jews were described as "scurrilous, stupid, and tight-fisted", but after the Jewish Emancipation and the rise of Jews to the middle- or upper-class in Europe were portrayed as "clever, devious, and manipulative financiers out to dominate [world finances]" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisemitism#Economic_antisemitism))

([See also: TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GreedyJew))

As for the imagery - large ears and noses, you should find good examples from Nazi-era propaganda posters, maybe I'll add some after a search later.

Note that I'm not saying that in both cases the character designers were intentionally hateful antisemites, but I think it's fair to say that they used visual and other tropes also very present in modern antisemitism.

Comment: `but in both cases the character designers where influnced by the same antisemite stereotypes` Got a source for that?

Comment: No. But the same stereotypes are present. Why should I assume that the greedy, big nosed, big eared merchant was invented independently in these cases, when the trope and visuals cues are older?

Comment: "they used visual and other tropes also very present in ..." - this might move the answer beyond the scope laid out in the question, that the similarity should not be based upon a "simple description whose conception predates Star Trek and Star Wars". FWIW, [Forgotten Trek](http://ottens.co.uk/forgottentrek/creating-the-ferengi/) lists as inspirations for the Ferengi "I just looked around at 80s America where greed was good and Gekko was one of our heroes.", "[The Ferengi] could provide the ideal contrast to Gene Roddenberry’s highly evolved crew.", and "the Ferengi would stand in for the ...

Comment: ... forces of unrestrained capitalism". Concerning the visual appearance, it says "the idea was to take them away from looking like us but of course they do look like us in some ways." and early drafts "had distinct echoes of ancient Babylonian sculptures". Lastly, it should be noted that in their first appearance (and in the original plan), the Ferengi were quite a bit more warlike than the mere greedy (and not always very smart) traders that they appeared as in later installments. With all these in mind, the similarities to antisemitic stereotyping may or may not be coincidental.

Comment: I don't think Space Jews are an old trope like lizard men. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceJews

Comment: @mart: That link provides some more interesting conjecture specifically referring to the Ferengi (highlight added): 'Ferengi are seen by some as antisemitic characters, and their earliest appearances were criticized as being **Japanese** stereotypes. In reality, the Ferengi were meant to be strawmen for **American capitalists in general**, and were compared to "Yankee Traders" in their first appearance. The name 'Ferengi' is derived from an Arabic and Hindi slur for white people. The comparisons to Jewish stereotypes came in after they were ditched as villains and became comic relief. (...)'

Comment: I think antisemitic (incl. Arab)/anti-German/anti-Japanese stereotypes and Ferengis have shared cultural ancestry, but that's different from one being inspired the other. Part of character design is trying to embody personality traits in physical traits, and we typically associated corrupted morality with deformed physique. Being hunched over, sickly looking, physically feeble, etc. are often associated with avarice. Exaggerating facial proportions is part of that theme. So Ferengis have exaggerated ears and comical-looking large noses.

Comment: And because we're all socialized to be familiar with antisemitic stereotypes and associate them with greed, that connection feels particularly strong when we don't make that association with non-greedy characters that also have similar exaggerated features (fantasy dwarves/ogres, Rumpelstiltskin, several male Disney villains, etc.).

Comment: Fantasy dwarves are oftehn greedy, starting at least with Tolkien. I don't recall that set of physical characteristics (smallich or hunched, big nose, big ears) from other aliens in DS9 or TNG (but it's been a long while since I bingewatched those, so could be wrong). I don't know if the association hunched over - avarice is older than modern antisemitism. I know that they are very much entangled today.

Comment: Images work precisly because they carry more associations and other baggage than we consciously notice. Including baggage we should leave at the station.

Answer (score 4):

## This Guy

[image: Evazan a humanoid creature with a disfigured face: large nose; left side of his face looks burnt with a missing eye]

[Dr Cornelius Evazan](https://www.starwars.com/databank/doctor-cornelius-evazan).  [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cornelius_Evazan) suggests that he is *human*, but the Databank doesn't indicate a species, so he could very well be alien!

## And the Tellarites

[image: A Tellarite; a pink skinned humanoid with black holes for eyes and an upturned pig nose; he is very bushy haired all over the head]

From *Star Trek: TOS*.

Just looking at these two, they both have 'snouts' rather than noses and I think that they look rather like each other!

Answer (score 1):

Well the Orions from Star Trek and Twi'leks from Star Wars are pretty similar.

Female Twi'leks have been considered especially attractive and slender, which made them favorite subjects for slavery and entertainment. [link](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Twi%27lek)

Orion females were very animalistic in nature, known for their extreme carnal appetites and their innate skill of seduction. A Human male could rarely resist the alluring dance of the Orion slave girl. [link](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Orion)

Comment: The wording of the question excludes Orions on two counts: (a) they have human facial features, (b) green skin predates both works.

Comment: Well, even if they weren't discounted by the question, they just don't look that similar.  One has head-tantacles and the other doesn't.

Comment: A sex slave is not a new idea either.