# In Star Wars: IV and Star Trek: III, are this guy and this guy the same guy?

Tags: star-trek, star-wars, a-new-hope, actor-identification, the-search-for-spock

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108442/3823) to this question:

[Is there a pair of alien species, one in Star Wars, one in Star Trek, that are too similar for coincidence?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102724/is-there-a-pair-of-alien-species-one-in-star-wars-one-in-star-trek-that-are-t)

@BenitoCiaro remembered these two characters:

[image]
[image]

One from *Star Wars IV: A New Hope*, the other from *Star Trek III: The Search for Spock*.

They look like the same **actor** to me.

## Are these guys the same guy?

Comment: Kardue'sai'Malloc is the alien from the cantina. Aside from the fact that the mask was created by Rick Baker, there is no readily available information as to who the actor behind the mask was.

Comment: I've asked on a FB group full of people who either worked on the movies, or who know the people who did. I should be able to get an answer about the actor.

Comment: You can see a picture of the mask without an actor in it [here](http://www.tomspinadesigns.com/star-wars-prop-restoration.html)--since it's a full face mask, I assume the real extra wearing it might have looked quite different.

Comment: I find it fascinating and surprising, that through all this discussion and research, and the conclusion that the answer is almost certainly *no*, **no one has rejected the premise that they really do look the same in the pictures above!**.   Apparently, **Allan Miller really does look like the devil.**

Comment: You racist humans.. you think all of us Devaronians look alike!

Answer (score 22):

## The Star Trek guy

As user Nathan K. Campbell already pointed out, the alien from *The Search for Spock*, who McCoy tries to secure passage to Genesis through, is played by **Allan Miller:**

- [Allan Miller Bio at Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Allan_Miller)
- [Allan Miller Filmography at IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0587863/)

Miller's filmography does not include *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*.  Usually, IMDb filmographies include uncredited roles; that being said, these filmographies are not always complete or 100% accurate.

## The Star Wars guy

Turning to the character of [Kardue'sai'Malloc](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kardue'sai'Malloc) (aka "Labria") in *A New Hope*, it is somewhat of a mystery as to who plays this "devil".  It is widely known that he was inserted into the scene at the last minute, because costume designer [Rick Baker](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000711/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) happened to have a devil mask on hand that he liked.

I suspected that Baker himself may have played Kardue'sai'Malloc himself.  In researching this, I stumbled upon the following old web page from the **"Red 6" project** (which is dedicated to compiling the character and actor names of everyone who has ever appeared on screen in Star Wars):

- [Cantina Creatures](http://red6.home.insightbb.com/Aliens/Cantina1/Index.htm)

It asserts that Kardue'sai'Malloc was

> ***“Most likely Phil Tippett or Rick Baker...”***

For the record, Tippett played Doikk Na'ts in the Cantina band.

## Miller's switch from TV to silver screen, and filming locations

According to Allan Miller's filmography linked above, he worked *exclusively in television* until 1977. His first credited film role was in [*MacArthur*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076342/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_87) (1977) — interestingly, the same year as *SW:IV*.  However, production on *SW:IV* was based at two studios (Elstree and Shepperton) in the UK, with filming locations in Tunisia, Guatemala, and Arizona.

Specifically, according to

> Hearn, Marcus, *The Cinema of George Lucas*, Harry N. Abrahams, Inc., 2005, p.116-117,

the interior of the Mos Eisley scene was filmed at Elstree Studios in the UK.  In the years 1976-1977, Allan Miller was filming various TV series in California as well as *MacArthur* on a Universal Studios lot in California.

**Given his demanding TV schedule (appearances in several series at once), all in the Hollywood area, it seems very unlikely that Miller would have travelled to the UK to be part of the Cantina scene there.  He also had no family or personal connections that would have brought him to the UK for other reasons.**

## Upshot

Based on the information above, there is no evidence that the bar alien in *ST:III* and the Cantina devil in *SW:IV* are played by the same actor.  Rather, the timing, locations, and anecdotes suggest that they were almost certainly played by **different actors**.

Comment: Note:  Phil Tippet is the monster responsible for the carnage in the original *Jurassic Park*:  http://cdn.acidcow.com/pics/20150805/funniest_tumblr_13.jpg

Comment: http://imag.manicomic.com/general/phil-tippett-mis-respetos.png

Answer (score 11):

The actor in STIII is Alan Miller:

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Allan_Miller

He does not appear to have a connection to Star Wars

The alien in the cantina is [Kardue'sai'Malloc](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kardue'sai'Malloc) per Wookieepedia and was a played with an actor in a Rick Baker mask:

Here is a better picture in which you can see it is certainly a mask and bears little resemblance to Mr. Miller.

[image]

Note: Praxis addressed the following idea more coherently in his subsequent answer so be sure to check that answer as well if this is interesting / compelling reasoning:

It isn't unreasonable to think since SW was released in 1977 and STIII in 1984, the character design might have been an influence but it is almost certainly not the same person. Consider also that Miller is primarily an American actor and A New Hope was shot in the UK (of course there were American actors there - that isn't my point) - the point being that by all accounts this was a throwaway character added in at the last minute to give the scene more 'character'. It is unlikely it would have been a casting call type part and there is no indication that Miller was in the UK or Star Wars.

Comment: Don't imdb and other sources usually only list actors with speaking roles, or at least ones with characters named onscreen? The guy in Star Wars may have just been an extra.

Comment: imdb lists whomever is added to their database. unnamed extras often make it in, having been added by someone in the know.

Comment: Sometimes actors are not credited or IMDb is not complete.   We need to determine the name of actor in SW to complete this answer.   As it stands now, it's inconclusive.

Comment: The character was also identified as [Labria](http://zorg.ws/starwarsdb/index.php?title=Labria) in various places, on [this toy](http://www.rebelscum.com/POTF2cantinaaliens.asp) for example, so that could be a useful alternate search term for people trying to google info about the character.

Comment: I suspect it was Baker himself who put on the mask for an insert shot--if you look at [this page](http://johnrozum.blogspot.com/2007/05/star-wars-30th-anniversary-special-part_23.html), it has a number of images of Baker wearing costumes he'd designed, and [this image of Baker in a corpse-like mask](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_TFBFHx0gM8k/RlHqme5HADI/AAAAAAAAAhY/_mGqcEHpGTc/s1600/cantinastennesbaker.jpg) reminds me of the Star Wars cantina character in terms of the proportions of the face, particularly how far apart the eyes and their size relative to the rest of the face.

Comment: Also, it says [here](http://thenewstarwarsmovie.com/starwars-a-new-hope-trivia/) that "The horned alien seen in the Cantina sequence was originally a devil mask created by Rick Baker for a Halloween show" -- if he designed it for a Halloween show that probably means it was designed to fit his own face.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not convinced yet.   It still looks like the same eyes, nose, smile lines and chin to me.   But, I suppose the fact one is a mask and the other is not is nearly proof of **no**.

Comment: It isn't unreasonable to think since SW was released in 1977 and STIII in 1984, the character design might have been an influence but it is almost certainly not the same person. Consider also that Miller is primarily an American actor and A New Hope was shot in the UK (of course there were American actors there - that isn't my point) - the point being that by all accounts this was a throwaway character added in at the last minute to give the scene more 'character'. It is unlikely it would have been a casting call type part and there is no indication that Miller was in the UK or Star Wars.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell:   Those are good points which might as well be added to the answer to show the truth is **almost certainly no**.

Comment: @Praxis - apologies - however, if you see the comment thread, you'll see that I had already commented re: the UK connection - so it wasn't stolen - I simply moved my thoughts into the answer per the OP suggestion. Happy to remove it if it is indeed bad form - but I think I made the point first, just in a different location :)

Comment: Is it possible that the same person or group designed the two characters?

Comment: @jpmc26 - does not seem to be likely as Rick Baker did not work on Star Trek III 

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088170/fullcredits/

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell : It was a misunderstanding.   Apologies!  :-)  (And for the record, great answer; I had +1'ed it.)

Answer (score 9):

### Update!

[Penny McCarthy](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0565290/) signs [autographs of Labria](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bkocq6zl-6l/?taken-by=a_wind_to_shake_the_stars), as

> Penny McCarthy
>   Labria

[image: Penny McCarthy - Labria]

Original research below:

---

We already know that the Star Trek alien was played by [Alan Miller](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0587863/), the real question is just who played Labria in Star Wars.

This is an interesting issue because no one really seems to know for absolute sure. Amongst the community of Star Wars BTS-uber-fans, the consensus is that it is most *likely* [Rick Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Baker_%28makeup_artist%29), as it was Baker's mask that was used, and Baker is known to have donned a few masks for various pickup shots in the Mos Eisley Cantina. But for some reason, no one has been able to verify whether or not Baker in that specific mask.

The most conclusive evidence we have is [an old article about Baker](https://neatocoolville.blogspot.de/2008/04/rick-baker-goes-bananas-with-star-wars.html), which includes a photo of him wearing the mask in question.

[image: rick baker in the mask]

The eyes between Baker and the on-screen actor look similar, but it's pretty hard to say for certain, and the article doesn't mention him wearing it on-screen.

### HOWEVER

I asked about this in [a Facebook Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/starwarsrarevintagephotos/) whose membership includes not only extremely knowledgeable fans, but many people who worked on the films. In addition to the Rick Baker theory, a member related some information that they had found.

Apparently, at one point, Phil Tippett mentioned a part-time librarian at ILM named Jibralta Merrill being one of the faces behind the masks in the Cantina. Supposedly according to her, [Penny McCarthy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Penny_McCarthy) was the person wearing the Labria mask in the Cantina.

[image: FB]

Comment: Nice find!​​​​​​​

Comment: I'm going to keep digging to see if i can find better confirmation than third-hand facebook stories, but I think we can definitely rule out them being the same person.

Answer (score 2):

In a recent Joe Rogan episode:

[Rick Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Baker) the special effects/make up artist on Star Wars, mentioned that they had very little money and the Cantina aliens are just guys in various masks they had lying around, like "werewolf" and "devil"(this is the one we're talking about). Most likely: The same mask was re-used in another film. It's a common industry practice.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, Kardue'sai'Malloc was portrayed by a lady called [Penny McCarthy](https://www.londonfilmandcomiccon.com/index.php/9-lfcc-guests/london-guests-filmandtv/1161-penny-mccarthy), who was an auditor at Lucasfilm or Fox.

She was at the 2018 London Film and Comic Con in the end of July and the billed image was the following:
[image: Penny McCarthy's image for 2018 London Film and Comic Con]

Comment: Dupe information of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109463/23243