# In DS9 episode 5.15 (By Inferno's Light) is one of the prisoners wearing Leia's Boushh helmet from Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, star-trek-ds9, return-of-the-jedi

In Return of the Jedi we see Leia wearing a [Boushh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boushh) helmet.

[image]

In [Deep Space Nine](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/star-trek-deep-space-nine-synopsis) [episode 5.15](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/By_Inferno's_Light_(episode)) (By Inferno's Light) we see a prisoner wearing what appears to be the same helmet.

My question is: **In DS9 episode 5.15 (By Inferno's Light) is one of the prisoners wearing Leia's Boushh helmet from Return of the Jedi?**

Comment: Hawkguy, I thought it was very similar to Leia's helmet from Return of the Jedi when I first caught sight of the Breen as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not the same prop, nor is it a replication of it.  While the Breen (the episode you're asking about is the first appearance) wear suits that look a great deal like the Boushh costume, that's as far as the connection goes.

Here you can see many details differ between Boushh and Breen:

[image: Picture of Breen prisoner]

The top of the Breen helmet is taller than Boushh, there's one 'eye' slit in the Breen helmet vs. 2 in the Boushh helmet.  And the Breen helmet lacks Boushh's distinctive snout design.

Answer (score 3):

Besides @Keen's answer, see @Praxis's answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102727/3823) which I have included below, which talks about the origin of the Breen design.

---

## The Breen vs. the Ubese bounty hunters

[image]

This is probably the best and most definitive example of a character's appearance being copied between the two works.  Many Internet forums report the existence of an interview in which *Deep Space Nine* costume designer Robert Blackman addressed the Breen issue explicitly, indicating that the Breen helmet was **based directly** on the Ubese helmet (specifically, Leia's in *Return of the Jedi*), and that this was intended as an homage.

If I can locate a transcript or video of the interview, I will add it here.